# How to make a variable containing a symlink to a directory expand in bash for loop?

Tags: bash

Suppose that I have a directory `dir` in my `$HOME`, let's make `symlink` to it.

```
ln -s "$HOME/dir" "$HOME/.toDir"
```

Then, we introduce a variable containing that `symlink`

```
TO_DIR="$HOME/.toDir"
```

I want to enumerate all the files in the directory pointing by `TO_DIR` without parsing the `ls` output which is considered a bad practice (but it works !) , I tried without success using a for loop:

```
for file in "$TO_DIR"/*
do
  # do something with $file
done
```

I get no files, it seems that the `$TO_DIR` didn’t expand to the directory.

**Update**: it works from the command-line (interactively)  , but not from a shell script.

Comment: Try `TO_DIR="$HOME/.toDir"` instead of `TO_DIR="$HOME/toDir"`

Comment: Possible typo `TO_DIR` / `TO_DOR`?

Comment: @StefanosKalantzis I use bash 4.2.25 too, it works for me from the command-line but it failed when I write it as s script.

Comment: Shouldn't that be in the question ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TO_DIR="$HOME/.toDir"

for f in $TO_DIR/*; do
    echo $f
done
```

and it worked correctly:

```
$ ./test.bsh 
/home/stefanos/.toDir/a
/home/stefanos/.toDir/b
```

Maybe you tried to set the variable `TO_DIR` *outside* of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Use command `readlink`.

```
readlink symlink
```

will output target of symlink. Watch out, and do not invoke it like this `readlink symlink/`.

Answer (score -2):

You'd be better off using something like this instead:

```
find -L "$TO_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read filename; do
  dosomething "$filename"
done
```

This way we're asking find to find all files in "$TO_DIR", the -L 
switch tells it to follow symlinks. We also protect the loop against
failures due to filename having spaces in them by reading the
filename one at a time per line using the while loop. For the for loop
it will break filenames with spaces in them into individual chunks
split at the spaces.

The above will also find files with name like "$TO_DIR/.hidden" so you
might want to watch out for that.

Comment: This will fail for the same reason that parsing `ls` is not recommended: a filename containing a newline.